# APDU Command help 80 72

Tags: apdu

80 72 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 11 72 76 11
80 76 00 9F 08 16 08 45 44 A4 5A F6 5C
80 74 00 9F 08 6E C3 1A C8 B3 A9 4C 6C

what does this command do?
ISO 7816-4 8.1.2

Answer (score 0):

According to ISO 7816-4 CLA byte (0x80) in this command denotes proprietary class. So, this command is card or app dependent. It looks like command 'CREDIT PSAM' from EN 1546-3, but I don't know exactly. It depends on details.